# jquery append after ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My situation:
I have a element that through AJAX loads search results into the element.
html

```
<input class="search">
<div class="search-results">
  // in default is empty
  // after search add <a></a>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("input.search").change(function() {
   $(".search-results").append('<div class="searchResultsOverlay"></div>');
});
```

how to append (jquery)  elemtent after results load?
I try .change on input, but this is partially solution. When I using .change function, append is working on enter or click outside input, but if I let cursor in input, results is loaded and append waiting for a action (enter, click).

How do I call jQuery after Ajax add content?

thx

Comment: have you page had the jquery

Comment: There is no ajax request in your code, if there was please provide your ajax call, and tell us why you did't place your code there.

Comment: try putting jquery function inside AJAX success function after ajax load search thing is done

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax()` returns an jqXHR object with all the methods of a `Promise`. Therefore you can use the `.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {})` to execute code when the result of your XHR is returned.

As an example ...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
})
.done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
});
```

Here are some other methods available from the jqXHR object

```
jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

Take a look here for more information on each of them: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's keyup event

```
$(".search").keyup(function() {
   $(".search-results").html('<div class="searchResultsOverlay"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the property `success` in the ajax data object, it's the callback function. Then do whatever in the block of `success`.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(response) {
        /* Whatever; response is the server response */
    }
});
```